# Are you able to solve it? JavaScript carousel implementation using an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I cannot solve this problem, are you able to solve it? I would need your expert advice on how to do it in JS vanilla or jQuery (optional).
A sample of code on jsfiddle would be high appreciated.

I have to display an array of 5 elements in a  list with a limit of 3 at one time

```
var range = [0,1,2,3,4];

<ul>
  <li>0</li>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
</ul>

<div id="prev">prev</div>
<div id="next">next</div>
```

When user click on "next", I need to add a class "focus" on the first "li".

```
<ul>
  <li class="focus">0</li>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
</ul>
```

Second click on "next"

```
<ul>
  <li>0</li>
  <li class="focus">1</li>
  <li>2</li>
</ul>
```

click on "next" ...

```
<ul>
  <li>0</li>
  <li>1</li>
  <li class="focus">2</li>
</ul>
```

click on "next" ... note array shift

```
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li class="focus">3</li>
</ul>
```

click on "next" ... array shift

```
<ul>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li class="focus">4</li>
</ul>
```

click on "next" ... but I cannot go any further as there is not element in the array to be displayed, so if I clicking "prev" I would like have the reverse

click on "prev" …

```
<ul>
  <li>2</li>
  <li class="focus">3</li>
  <li>4</li>
</ul>
```

click on "prev" …

```
<ul>
  <li class="focus">2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
</ul>
```

click on "prev" … note array shift

```
<ul>
  <li class="focus">1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
</ul>
```

click on "prev" … note array shift

```
<ul>
  <li class="focus">0</li>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
</ul>
```

click on "prev" … nothing happen it has we reach the beginning go the array

```
<ul>
  <li class="focus">0</li>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
</ul>
```

Any idea? Thanks in advance

Revised solutions as suggested in answers

http://jsfiddle.net/QwATR/

Comment: When writing complex JavaScript, it helps increase your productivity to use a library like jQuery, even though normally I would be all for vanilla JavaScript.

Comment: Hi Alex, yes jquery would be great, I spent several time but I have problem to figure out the algorithm..... would you have an idea how to solve it? Thanks for your comment. Any idea are welcome :-)

Comment: Do you have a [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net) of what you currently have?

Comment: Have you made an attempt yet?  Please provide that code.

Comment: Hi James, I spent several time on it with result of being able to move on NEXT but buggy on moving at PREV here my code added to my question.. would you able to help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is quite straightforward in vanilla javascript ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sBF6b/7/))

```
var range = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
    lis = document.getElementsByTagName('li'),
    foc, offset = 0;
function next() {
    if (foc === undefined) {
        foc = 0;
    } else if (foc < lis.length - 1) {
        foc++;
    } else if (offset + foc < range.length - 1) {
        offset++;
    }
    rewriteList();
}
function previous() {
    if (foc === undefined) {
        foc = 0;
    } else if (foc > 0) {
        foc--;
    } else if (offset > 0) {
        offset--;
    }
    rewriteList();
}
function rewriteList() {
    for (var i = 0; i < lis.length; i++) {
        lis[i].innerHTML = range[i + offset];
        lis[i].className = i == foc ? 'focus' : '';
    }
}
document.getElementById('prev').onclick = previous;
document.getElementById('next').onclick = next;
```

Alternatively you could set up the carousels with a constructor function ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sBF6b/8/))

Comment: @GibboK Did my answer somehow become incorrect to warrant the unaccept? Obviously, once the actual code was available it becomes trivial to reverse-engineer the jQuery back to regular JavaScript...

Comment: This won't work in IE5.5, IE6, IE7, or IE8 by the way. And IE8 alone currently has 23.52% of the desktop browser market share.

Comment: @AlexW thanks, I think that's due to `addEventListener`? I'm reverting to `onclick` for the time being.

Answer (score 3):

```
// Initalize everything
var curPos = 0;
var minIndex = 0;
var maxIndex = 2;
var clicks = 0;
var range = ['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10'];
if($('li.focus').length === 0)
{
    $('ul > li:eq(0)').addClass('focus');
    $('ul > li').each(function(index){
       $(this).text(range[index+curPos]);
    });
}

// Next click handler
$('#next').click(function(){
    if($('ul li').index($('li.focus')) < 2)
    {
        $('li.focus').removeClass('focus');
        if(curPos < 2)
            curPos++;
        else
        {
            clicks++;
        }
        $('ul > li:eq('+curPos+')').addClass('focus');
    } else {
       if(clicks < range.length -3)
           clicks++;
    }
    $('ul > li').each(function(index){
        $(this).text(range[index+clicks]);
    });
});

// Previous click handler
$('#prev').click(function(){
    if($('ul li').index($('li.focus')) > 0)
    {
        $('li.focus').removeClass('focus');
        if(curPos > 0)
            curPos--;
        else
        {
            clicks--;
        }
        $('ul > li:eq('+curPos+')').addClass('focus');
    } else {
        if(clicks > 0)
            clicks--;
    }
        $('ul > li').each(function(index){
            $(this).text(range[index+clicks]);
        });
    console.log('clicks after prev:' + clicks);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/QAsQj/2/

Comment: I thanks, but I just tried your jsfiddle, but seems it is not working. I need to show shifting the array all 5 elements... this is the tricky part.. any idea how to solve it?

Comment: so the ul element should show 0-1-2 next 1-2-3 next 2-3-4 when the focus is on the last li item

Comment: Hi Alex, I kindly as you your help, as I am not able to implement your suggestion in my code. Could you please help me out? Here link to my new question. Many thanks in advance: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18172448/not-able-to-swift-an-array

Answer (score 2):

```
$(function(){
    $("#next").click(function(){
        if($(".focus").length == 0){
            $("ul li:first-child").addClass("focus");
        }
        else{
            if($(".focus").is(":last-child")){
                $("ul li").each(function(){
                    var content = $(this).next("li").html();
                    $(this).empty().html(content);
                }
                $(".focus").html(/**WHATEVER YOUR NEXT CONTENT IS**/);
            }
            else{
                var active = $(".focus");
                $("ul li").removeClass("focus");
                active.next("li").addClass("focus");
            }
        }
    }
    );
    $("#prev").click(function(){
        if($(".focus").length == 0){
            break;
        }
        else{
            if($(".focus").is(":first-child")){
                $("ul li").each(function(){
                    var content = $(this).prev("li").html();
                    $(this).empty().html(content);
                }
                $(".focus").html(/**WHATEVER YOUR PREV CONTENT IS**/);
            }
            else{
                var active = $(".focus");
                $("ul li").removeClass("focus");
                active.prev("li").addClass("focus");
            }
        }
    }
    );
}
);
```

Comment: I'm playing with a fiddle now.  Stand by.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/G4Spe/ here's a starter example.  I'm finessing the stops on either end

Comment: Here it is.  Working how you wanted. Had to revamp my original answer as it was initially untested. http://jsfiddle.net/G4Spe/1/

Comment: Well does this seem to accomplish what you require?

Comment: Hi, unfortunatelly I am not able to implement your suggestion in my code. Could you please help me out? Here link to my new question. Many thanks in advance: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18172448/not-able-to-swift-an-array