# Shift an array and rendering it in a html list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, algorithm

Using the following script I am not able to swift and set the focus for an array back in the list when clicking PREV.

It should work as this example:

http://jsfiddle.net/QAsQj/2/

my code here

http://jsfiddle.net/Eq4js/

Could you point me out what am I doing wrong here, I would appreciate a sample of code on

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <style>
            .focus { color: red; }
        </style>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>  

        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                var snippet = {
                    index: 0,
                    indexNew: 0,
                    start: 0,
                    $el: 'div.snippet-categories',
                    config: {
                        itemsVisible: 4
                    },
                    data: {
                        items: {
                            models: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
                        }
                    },
                    navigate: function(direction) {
                        if (direction === 'right') {
                            if (this.index < this.config.itemsVisible - 1) {
                                if (this.index < this.config.itemsVisible - 1) {
                                    this.index++;
                                    var result = '#' + this.index + '';
                                    $('li.focus').removeClass('focus');
                                    $(result).addClass('focus');
                                } else {
                                    this.start++;
                                }
                            } else {

                                if (this.start < this.data.items.models.length - this.config.itemsVisible) {
                                    this.start++;
                                    this.renderItems();
                                    var result = '#' + (this.config.itemsVisible - 1 + this.start) + '';
                                    $('li.focus').removeClass('focus');
                                    $(result).addClass('focus');
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        else if (direction === 'left') {
                            if (this.index > this.config.itemsVisible - 1) {
                                if (this.index > this.config.itemsVisible - 1) {
                                    this.index--;
                                    (Focus.to(this.getFocusable(-1, true)));
                                } else {
                                    this.start++;
                                }
                            } else {
                                if (this.start > this.data.items.models.length - this.config.itemsVisible) {
                                    this.index--;
                                    this.renderItems();
                                } else {
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    render: function() {
                        this.renderItems();
                    },
                    renderItems: function(reverse) {
                        var reverse = reverse || false;
                        var html = '', result = '', subset = null;
                        var range = this.data.items.models;
                        var limit = range.length - this.config.itemsVisible;
                        if (this.indexNew !== null) {
                            if (reverse === false) {
                            } else {
                            }
                            subset = range.slice(this.start, this.start + this.config.itemsVisible);
                            var i = 0;
                            while (i < subset.length) {
                                var x = subset[i];
                                result += '<li id="' + this.data.items.models[x] + '" data-idx="' + this.data.items.models[x] + '" class="focusable">' + this.data.items.models[x] + '</li>';
                                i++;
                            }

                            html = result + '</ul>';
                            var el = $(this.$el);
                            el.empty();
                            el.append(html);
                        } else {
                            console.log('limit STOP');
                        }
                    },
                };

                snippet.render();

                $('#next').click(function() {

                    snippet.navigate("right");

                });
                $('#prev').click(function() {
                    snippet.navigate("left");
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="snippet-categories"></div>
        <div id="prev">prev</div>
        <div id="next">next</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

This question is related to

[Are you able to solve it? JavaScript carousel implementation using an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18167357/are-you-able-to-solve-it-javascript-carousel-implementation-using-an-array/18167488#comment26617470_18167488)

Comment: Could you put up a fiddle with your code.

Comment: Hi, here the link http://jsfiddle.net/Eq4js/ many thanks in advance

Comment: Here's a hint: Imagine you're concurrently moving through 2 arrays with different sizes at the same time, a single step at a time, which can be either forward or backward. Your first concern is not to go over bounds in either, so each time you take a step you should check whether your current **positions** in either array would result in out of bounds - if so, you just don't move in the array in which it does. The result is: when you get to the index of the smaller array, each step forward is taken only in the larger one until it's end index is reached, etc. Hope this helps...

Comment: Thanks Stefan, for your comment +1

Comment: I'm just curious and google isn't helping. What does it mean to "swift an array"?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, actually it was my typo in the title :-) I have corrected it.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I solved it

Algo example here
http://jsfiddle.net/QwATR/

```
Snippet_Categories = (function(Snippet) {

    var Snippet_Categories = function() {
        this.config = {
            curPos: 0, // index for selected element
            itemVisible: 4, // number of items visible
            minIndex: 0, // define visible area start
            maxIndex: 4 - 1, // define visible area end  = "itemVisible -1"
            outItems: 0                     // number of element out of visible area
        };
        this.data = {
            items: arguments[1].items
        };
        this.construct.apply(this, arguments);
    };

    $.extend(true, Snippet_Categories.prototype, Snippet.prototype, {
        init: function() {
            this.index = 0;     // set default index
            this.indexNew = 0; // set next index 
            this.start = 0;
            this.render();
        },
        create: function() {
            return this.parent.$el.find('.snippet-categories');
        },
        removeFocus: function() {
            var test = $('li.focus');
            Focus.blur(test);
            //$('li.focus').removeClass('focus');
        },
        focus: function() {

            //$('ul > li:eq(' + this.config.curPos + ')').addClass('focus');
            var test = $('ul > li:eq(' + this.config.curPos + ')');

            return Focus.to(test, true);
        },
        render: function() {
            //debugger
            this.renderItems();
            this.focus();
        },
        renderItems: function() {
            var html = '<ul>';
            for (var i = 0; i < this.config.itemVisible; i++) {
                html += '<li data-idx="' + this.data.items.at(i + this.config.outItems).get('id') + '" class="">' + this.data.items.at(i + this.config.outItems).get('label') + '</li>';
            }
            html += '</ul>';
            $('.snippet-categories').empty();
            $('.snippet-categories').html(html);
        },
        navigate: function(direction) {
            if (direction === 'right') {
                if (this.config.curPos < this.config.maxIndex)
                {
                    this.removeFocus();
                    if (this.config.curPos < this.config.maxIndex)
                        this.config.curPos++;
                    else
                    {
                        this.config.outItems++;
                    }
                } else {
                    if (this.config.outItems < this.data.items.length - this.config.itemVisible)
                        this.config.outItems++;
                }
                this.renderItems();
                this.focus();
            }
            else if (direction === 'left') {
                if (this.config.curPos > this.config.minIndex)
                {
                    this.removeFocus();
                    if (this.config.curPos > this.config.minIndex)
                        this.config.curPos--;
                    else
                    {
                        this.config.clicks--;
                    }
                } else {
                    if (this.config.outItems > 0)
                        this.config.outItems--;
                }
                this.renderItems();
                this.focus();
            }
        },
        onFocus: function() {
            //this.index = parseInt(Focus.focused[0].dataset.idx, 10);
            console.log('element in focus ' + this.index);
        }
    });

    return Snippet_Categories;

})(Snippet);
```